# How can I 'filter' the entire document using an external command in vim

Tags: php, vim

I have already got lint testing and code standards checking but I've like to go one further and add a hotkey to change all the code to a certain standard.

I have so far got as far as...

```
:r ! phpcbf --standard=psr2 %
```

But that only pulls the document in. So how can I make is just act like a filter and replace the entire script?

Comment: so thanks for they answers. now I have this im my config... map <F10> :%!phpcbf --standard=psr2<enter><enter>

Answer (score 2):

As described in [:help filter](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#filter), the general format for filtering content through an external program is

```
:{range}!{filter} [arg]
```

The expectation is that the filter command reads input on stdin and writes it to stdout.

For your tool, this likely translates to `:%!phpcbf --standard=psr2`.

Comment: Thank you too for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your command can take input from stdin you would do the following:

```
:%!phpcbf --standard=psr2
```

Please ready `:h filter`